# Setting up a DB2 database with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, db2

I'm trying to establish a connection with a DB2 database and my rails app using the ibm_db gem. However, much of the documentation available is a) very old and b) a bit too technical for me to understand. After installing the gem, I've updated my development database with the structure specified [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0705chun/) but when I try to start the Rails database I receive the error:

Failed to connect to [XXXXXX] due to: uncaught throw :"Connection failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1531N  The connection failed because the name specified with the DSN connection string keyword could not be found in either the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file or the db2cli.ini configuration file.  Data source name specified in the connection string: \"XXXXXXXX\". SQLCODE=-1531" (RuntimeError)

I know this means I need to create a db2dsdriver.cfg file but am unsure of where to start on how to create it and where to save it. The documents say I should model it after the .sample file that comes with the gem but I'm not sure what information goes where. You can see the sample file below:

```
<configuration>
   <dsncollection>
      <dsn alias="alias1" name="name1" host="server1.net1.com" port="50001"/>
      <!-- Long aliases are supported -->
      <dsn alias="longaliasname2" name="name2" host="server2.net1.com" port="55551">
         <parameter name="Authentication" value="SERVER_ENCRYPT"/>
      </dsn>
   </dsncollection>
   <databases>
      <database name="name1" host="server1.net1.com" port="50001">
         <parameter name="CurrentSchema" value="OWNER1"/>
         <wlb>
            <parameter name="enableWLB" value="true"/>
            <parameter name="maxTransports" value="50"/>
         </wlb>
         <acr>
            <parameter name="enableACR" value="true"/>
         </acr>
         <specialregisters>
            <parameter name="CURRENT DEGREE" value="'ANY'"/>
         </specialregisters>
         <sessionglobalvariables>
            <parameter name="global_var1" value="abc"/>
         </sessionglobalvariables>
      </database>
      <!-- Local IPC connection -->
      <database name="name3" host="localhost" port="0">
         <parameter name="IPCInstance" value="DB2"/>
         <parameter name="CommProtocol" value="IPC"/>
      </database>
   </databases>
   <parameters>
      <parameter name="GlobalParam" value="Value"/>
      <!-- Client configuration for Optim Performance Manager Extended Insight (OPM EI) and Optim Configuration Manager (OCM)-->
      <!-- <parameter name="connectionSupervisorLibrary" value="/home/pureQuery/pqcmx"/> -->
      <!-- <parameter name="connectionSupervisorProperties" value="controllerURL=server1.net1.com:65000,httpControllerURL=http://ibmdatacmserver:12206,cmxUUID=myuuid"/> -->
   </parameters>
</configuration>
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/ibmdb/ruby-ibmdb

Comment: That's the gem I'm already using...

Comment: Is Rails running on the same machine as DB2?   If not, which DB2 client package did you install?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old post but hit on it today.

Could you let us know what are you specifying in your database.yml file.

You need not worry about having the database and related info specified in dsdriver.cfg You can directly specify in database.yml and it will get picked up.

Your database.yml file should look as below (assuming you are on Rails 4)

```
default: &default
  adapter: ibm_db
  username: praveen
  password: *******
  #schema: db2inst1
  #host: localhost
  #port: 50000
  #account: my_account
  #app_user: my_app_user
  #application: my_application
  #workstation: my_workstation
  #security: SSL
  #timeout: 10
  #authentication: SERVER
  #parameterized: false

development:
  <<: *default
  database: railsdb
```

You will need to specify the database,port,host,username and password details against the respective keys. If you are not sure how the sections in database.yml should actually look just create your rails app with the following command

rails new myapp -d ibm_db

The -d option generates the database.yml skeleton specific for ibm_db

Thanks

Praveen